# WP e-commerce remove button

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

For adding a product to cart by id I've got this code:

```
<form class="product_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>" method="post" name="1" id="product_143">
<input type="hidden" value="add_to_cart" name="wpsc_ajax_action">
<input type="hidden" value="143" name="product_id">
<button>+</button>
```

Is there a code to remove a item by id?

I've tried this:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>" method="post" class="adjustform remove">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="wpsc_update_quantity" value="true">
<input type="submit" value="-">
</form>
```

But this removes the first item in the cart.

Comment: I believe the hidden "key" value defines what is being deleted.